# Docusign REST API - Composite template error

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am trying to create an envelope using a composite template. I created a server Template with roles for each signer. I would like to specify the role data at creation, attach a local side document and then overlay the server template for routing. I can get through auth, find the teplate ID everything up to creating the envelope.  Please see my JSON post below:

```
--MYBoundary

Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; 
{
"emailBlurb":"Test Email Body",
"emailSubject":"Test Email Subject",
"status":"created",
"compositeTemplates": [
{
"compositeTemplateId": "1",
"inlineTemplates": [
{
"sequence": "1",
"recipients": {
"signers" : [
{
"email": "email@mail.usf.edu",
"name": "Boss",
"recipientId": "1",
"roleName": "GM"
},
{
"email": "email@mail.usf.edu",
"name": "Name Here",
"recipientId": "3",
"roleName": "PX"
},
{
"email": "email@mail.usf.edu",
"name": "Diff Name",
"recipientId": "2",
"roleName": "OO"
}
]
}
}
],
"document": {
"documentId": "1",
"name": "LV_EOTF-Non-Mod_Commitment_Letter.DOCX"
},
"serverTemplates": [
{
"sequence": "2",
"templateId": "TempID"
}
]
}
]
}
--MYBoundary

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="LV_EOTF-Non-Mod_Commitment_Letter.DOCX"; documentid=1; compositeTemplateId=1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<Doc bytes here>
--MYBoundary--
```

I am getting the error response:

```
    {  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
"message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Template definition must include an 'envelopeTemplateDefinition' section."
}
```

I've searched every thread I could find and have tried emulating them. It just isn't working. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Update: The issue was the fact that I was accessing the Template Folder instead of the Envelope folder in the URL. This one about about drove me crazy...

Answer (score -3):

Can you please check the example provided by me in the below link.

[Several editable PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510595/several-editable-pdf)

The example shows how to create an envelope using servertemplate and inlinetemplate.

Comment: and what it is to do in an answer? it's better in comment

Comment: For above qs, it needs reputation of 50 to put the comment. and I dont have that reputation, that's why I have added an answer. So can you remove the downvote?